# Google Map Nearby search in Python

Tags: python, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to do a nearby search for schools,colleges and training institutes in python
My input would be **radius**,**Latitude of the user**,**Longitude of the user**
and the **search string**

I would like to get the result in json. 
I tried the below code. But it only give the address of the location i give. Is there any way to achieve this. Without the API key will be more preferable.

```
import requests
lat=12.967724
lon=77.628101
Search="hospital"
base = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
params = "latlng={lat},{lon}&sensor={sen}&q={search}".format(lat=12.957724, lon=99.628101, sen=False,search=Search)
url = "{base}{params}".format(base=base, params=params)
print url
response = requests.get(url)
responsej = response.json()
address = responsej[u'results'][0][u'formatted_address']
print address
```

Answer (score 1):

The geocoder deals with addresses.  For nearby search, use [the places API](https://developers.google.com/places/)